# Questioning whether question deserved to be closed

Tags: discussion, specific-question, allowed-topics

This question:
https://superuser.com/questions/164876/opinions-on-areca-backup

I was looking forward to getting people's opinions.  I haven't heard of the program before and wanted to know if others had and what they thought of it.

Answer (score 12):

[Super User](https://superuser.com/faq) (as well as Stack Overflow and Server Fault) is not the place to gauge opinions.

If you have a problem fixin' for a solution, yer in the right place.

But if you want to ask for thoughts on products so you can chew on the feedback and testimonials, it's just the wrong place at the wrong time.

Comment: This quote should be in the FAQ. It rather poignantly sums up what "off topic" means.

Comment: Well, I guess I have to accept this even though I still need "feedback and testimonials" to help with my decision.  Any recommendations on a good place to go?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8401/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-stack-overflow-questions @cch